# How do I drag and drop between two Files (Nautilus) windows when using Wayland on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nautilus, 20.04, wayland, drag-and-drop

I have switched to using Wayland on Ubuntu 20.04 because the unresolved copy and paste bug in Mutter made Libre Office Calc unusable for me.

When I open two folders side by side using Files (Nautilus), select a number of them in one window and drag to the other window a hand appears with a shadow containing a small blue circle with a cross inside. When I release the left mouse button the hand disappears and there is no obvious way to dump the files. When I right click, the context menu does not contain any option to release the transferred files and clicking on the paste option copies whatever is in the paste buffer from a previous operation.

If I carry out the identical operation using X11 the hand has no shadow and there is a small purple diamond with crossed arrows in it. The files are transferred as soon as I release the mouse button.

Comment: Probably this bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/845

Comment: It is not Mutter bug 845 because (1) this bug was closed 7 months ago (2) this bug effected drag and drop between different applications whereas my problem is with drag and drop between two windows of the same application (Files)